# Permission to execute denied for every file in /tmp

Tags: linux, memory, mount, file-permissions, dd-wrt

When I try to execute any program from the `/tmp` directory, it shows me `/tmp/file_name: Permission denied`. The same error is shown when I simply enter `/tmp`. The file system for `/tmp` is `ramfs`. I've tried `chmod 777 /tmp/file_name` but it returns the same error. `ls -l /tmp` shows `-dwxr-xr-x` before `file_name`. Running `mount` shows me:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
ramfs on /tmp type ramfs (rw,relatime)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=512K)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,mode=600)
```

I've tried `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` after which the output of `mount` did not change, and executing the program returned the same error. Running `mount -o remount,noexec /tmp` adds `noexec` to the `ramfs` line. Entering `/proc`, `/sys` or `/dev` also returns `Permission denied`.

Why is this happening and what should I do to execute the programs from `/tmp`? I'm doing this on a router running DD-WRT v24-sp2.

Comment: Should your tmp dir look like that? I would expect the sticky bit to be set.

Comment: Shouldn't I see a `t` in `ls -l /tmp` in that case?

Comment: Yes.  E.g. it could look like this: `drwxrwxrwt  30 root  wheel  6656 Apr 11 04:15 tmp` (last perm. part is t).